# Cannot Turn Windows Features on - Shadow Copy Error

Tags: windows-vista, installation

Whenever I try to install a Windows component (ex. an IIS Module) in the control panel, it runs for a bit and returns:

> An error has occurred. Not all the features were successfully changed.

The event viewer gives a clue:

> Ran out of time while expanding file specification \?\GLOBALROOT\Device\HarddiskVolumeShadowCopy24\Windows\softwaredistribution*.*.  This was being done for the WUA subscriber.
>
> Operation:
>     OnPostSnapshot event
>     PostSnapshot Event
>
> Context:
>     Execution Context: Shadow Copy Optimization Writer
>     Execution Context: Writer
>     Writer Class Id: {4dc3bdd4-ab48-4d07-adb0-3bee2926fd7f}
>     Writer Name: Shadow Copy Optimization Writer
>     Writer Instance ID: {8148cbcf-fe05-4607-821f-ec024a4fad7f}

Googling this turns up very little of substance.  This is a Vista machine which was recently upgraded from XP.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to temporarily disable the Volume Shadow Copy service (Windows Services) and install the IIS module. Before you do that, [create a system restore point](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/create-a-restore-point-for-windows-vistas-system-restore/). You'll never know.

Comment: Thanks!  That worked.  Well, more precisely, I had to disable it, install some things, re-enable it to install others, and after some trial and error it all got installed.  Very painful.  Thanks for the tip.